# Proving $E_\lambda(T)=E_{\lambda^{-1}}(T^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be an invertible linear operator on a finite-dimensional
>   vector space $V$. Prove that the eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to
>   $\lambda$ is the same as the eigenspace of $T^{-1}$ corresponding to
>   $\lambda^{-1}$.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Let $E_\lambda(T)$ denote the eigenspace of T. How can we conclude $E_\lambda(T)=E_{\lambda^{-1}}(T^{-1})$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $E_{\lambda}(T)=E_{\lambda^{-1}}(T^{-1})$ if $T$ is an invertible linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247405/prove-that-e-lambdat-e-lambda-1t-1-if-t-is-an-invertible-lin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$. Then, per definition, $Tv = \lambda v$. Multiplying this equation by $T^{-1}$ yields $T^{-1}Tv = T^{-1} \lambda v$. Since $\lambda \neq 0$ by the invertibility of $T$, this is equivalent to

$$T^{-1}v = \lambda^{-1} v.$$

But this precisely means that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^{-1}$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$. Since $v$ was arbitrary, the eigenspaces are the same.

Comment: I would contract the argumentation in one single expression:
\begin{align*} Tv&=\lambda v &\mid T^{-1}\\
T^{-1}(Tv)&=T^{-1}(\lambda v)\\
v&=\lambda T^{-1}(v)\\
\lambda^{-1}v&=T^{-1}(v)
\end{align*}